# Adding onclick event to img id

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I want to make an `img` where the `onclick` hides another `img` id and shows another one. This is the code I made:

```js
document.getElementById("poluzoom").addEventListener("click", changeimg);

function changeimg() {
  document.getElementById("poluzoom").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("readypol").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("textpolu").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<div id="fabricas">
  <img id="poluzoom" src="fabrica/fabricas.gif" alt="Mundo Zoom">
  <img id="readypol" src="poluicao/offbuton.png" alt="but1">
</div>
```

If I use `mouseover`, the function works, but with `onclick` it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works here : https://jsfiddle.net/Lskfyemy/1/, but we have a javascript error if `#textpolu` don't exists

Comment: what is "textpolu"?

Comment: Why not use jquery toggle()?

Comment: Because my teacher isn't expecting us to use JQuery, the textpolu is a h1 id that hides when clicked on that img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use Jquery `toggle()` see example http://jsfiddle.net/M9QBb/434/

```
<div id="fabricas">
  <img id="poluzoom" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Mundo Zoom">
  <img id="readypol" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="but1" style="display: none">
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$("#fabricas").click(function() {
  $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Works and that's more clean than what i had, thank you

Comment: @AndreFIlipe I thought you said you're not supposed to use jQuery?

Comment: @Barmar As long as i give a good justification  it's fine, either way, i kept the old code commented and corrected where i was doing wrong

Comment: @Barmar I answered the question 3 mins before Andre commented... Not a mind reader... sorry

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith My comment was directed to Andre. I was wondering why he accepted this answer.